# Firestore value field keeps increasing in local storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **firestore** and **firebase (v.9.19.1)** in a Svelte application.

After enabling offline persistence, I noticed that aside from the expected IndexedDB, I have several fields in the local storage.

Among them, one field:  `firestore_sequence_number_firestore/client/[app_name]` constantly increases its value (around each second), even if the app is idle or the local dev server is not running. I do an initial query to fetch some documents from a collection but nothing else afterwards.

**Does anyone know the reason for this field and why it keeps updating?** I used firestore with offline persistence in the past with AngularFire, and I have never seen this scenario before.

How I initialize firestore:

```
function initApp() {
  if (browser) {
    if (_firebaseApp) {
      return _firebaseApp;
    }
    _firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "client")
    return _firebaseApp;
  }
}

function initFirestore() {
  if (browser) {
    if (_firestoreDb) {
      return _firestoreDb;
    }
    const app = _firebaseApp ?? initApp();
    _firestoreDb = initializeFirestore(app, {
      localCache: persistentLocalCache({    
        cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
        tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager()
      })
    });
    return _firestoreDb;
  }
}
```

Comment: *firebaser here* My initial guess is that it's some kind of version number for the client, which [this code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/14ccbadd034e1a702f7d91e70ec14856d445764f/packages/firestore/src/local/shared_client_state_schema.ts#L143-L152) seems to confirm. But I don't know why it would increment every second, so I'm asking around.

Comment: Thanks, Frank, curious to know if this is expected behavior. I am indeed puzzled that the value keeps growing (not precisely every second, but still every 2-3 seconds) constantly.